# Table in which RowCount is stored in Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

Is there any system table in Sybase ASE which stores rowcount of all the user tables? I would like to avoid count(*). I know that we get rowcount when we use sp_help. So thought that it must be stored in any of system tables.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't use this feature in Sybase, but Sybase is quite similar to SQL Server.  Perusing through the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.tables/html/tables/tables34.htm), it would seem that the field is in `systabstats.rowcnt`.  This would result in a query something like this:

```
select o.name, s.rowcnt
from systabstats s join
     sysobjects o
     on s.id = o.id
where s.indid = 0;
```

I would imagine that this column is an approximation, and might be off in a high transaction environment.

Comment: Thanks Gordon ! SQL Server being almost similar to Sybase, sybase too has systabstats table which gave me the result.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the systabstats.rowcnt column: this information depends n whether the statistics have been updated. It is much better to use the row_count() function in a query against sysindexes. Unlike systabstats, this information is maintained automatically. Only when insert/delete activity is happening on the table can the result returned by this function temporarily be off by a small numbers of rows.

As for MSSQL Server still being similar to Sybase ASE: that's true on the outside. Microsoft has made many changes to the internals, and as a result the two databases are very different under the covers. Things like statistics and storage (both which we're discussing above) fall in this category.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SybaseASE pre 15.0 then

```
SELECT  o.name, 
        ROWCNT(i.doampg) as ROW_COUNT
    FROM  sysobjects o,
          sysindexes i
    WHERE o.id = i.id
    AND   o.sysstat2 & 1024 = 0         -- not remote
    AND   o.sysstat2 & 2048 = 0         -- not proxy
    AND   (i.indid = 0 OR i.indid = 1)  -- Heap or ClustIdx only
    --AND ROWCNT(i.doampg) > 1000         -- only need for tables having more than 1000 rows
    AND o.type = 'U'                    -- exclude system tables
    ORDER BY o.name
```

If you are running sybase 15.0 and up then you can use `ROW_COUNT()` function ;

```
SELECT  name, 
        ROW_COUNT(DB_ID(), id)
    FROM  sysobjects
    WHERE type = "U"
    AND   sysstat2 & 1024 = 0  -- not remote
    AND   sysstat2 & 2048 = 0  -- not proxy
    ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use systabstats.rowcnt or row_count (i.doampg) from sysindexes (ase15)

Comment: That code is correct, but for ASE12.5 and below, not for ASE 15.0 and above.